# Local representation of the projection $\Pi\colon \mathcal S\mathcal H\to \mathbb P\mathcal H$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, smooth-manifolds

**Background** Let $\mathcal H$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the scalar product of $\mathcal H$ (which is linear in the second argument) and $|\cdot|=\sqrt{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}$. Let $\mathcal S\mathcal H=\{\psi\in \mathcal H\mid |\psi|=1\}$ be the Hilbert sphere.

For any $\phi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H$, $\{(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{\phi\},v_\phi),(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\phi\},v_{-\phi})\}$ is a Hilbert atlas on $\mathcal S\mathcal H$.
\begin{align*}
v_\phi&\colon \chi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{\phi\}\mapsto \frac{\chi-\langle \phi,\chi\rangle\phi}{1-\langle \phi,\chi\rangle}\in \phi^\perp \\
v_{-\phi}&\colon \chi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\phi\}\mapsto \frac{\chi-\langle \phi,\chi\rangle\phi}{1+\langle \phi,\chi\rangle}\in \phi^\perp
\end{align*}

The collection $((U_\phi,u_\phi))_{\phi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H}$ is an atlas of the projective Hilbert space $\mathbb P \mathcal H$, where $U_\phi=\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \phi^\perp$ and
$$
u_\phi\colon \chi\in U_\phi\mapsto \frac{\chi}{\langle \phi,\chi\rangle}-\phi\in \phi^\perp\,.
$$

**Question** Now I want to find a suitable local description of the projection $\Pi\colon \mathcal S\mathcal H\to \mathbb P\mathcal H$. To do this, I fix $\psi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H$ and $\phi\in \psi^\perp$. Since $\psi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{\phi\}$, I consider the charts $(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{\phi\},v_\phi)$ and $(U_\psi,v_\psi)$, so that the local representation is
$$
u_\psi\circ \Pi\circ v_\phi^{-1}\colon \phi^\perp\cap U_\psi\to \psi^\perp
$$
Since
$$
v_\phi^{-1}(\xi)=\frac{|\xi|^2-1}{1+|\xi|^2}\phi+\frac{2}{1+|\xi|^2}\xi\,,
$$
I obtain
$$
(u_\psi\circ \Pi\circ v_\phi^{-1})\xi=\frac{(|\xi|^2-1)\phi+2\xi}{2\langle \psi,\xi\rangle}-\psi=\frac{|\xi|^2-1}{2\langle\psi,\xi\rangle}\phi+\bigg(\frac{\xi}{\langle \psi,\xi\rangle}-\psi\bigg)
$$

Are these calculations ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing my first answer because it needs to be corrected.

First, let me say that the expression of the chart $v_\phi$ is incorrect. Indeed, if $\dim_\mathbb C\mathcal H=N$ then $\mathcal S\mathcal H$ is a $(2N-1)$-real dimensional manifold. In particular, $\mathcal S\mathcal H$ can't be modelled on a $2(N-1)$-real dimensional vector space as $\phi^\perp$. The correct chart is
$$
v_\phi\colon \chi\in \mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{\phi\}\mapsto \frac{\chi-\Re\langle \phi,\chi\rangle\psi}{1-\Re\langle \phi,\chi\rangle}\in \{\xi\in \mathcal H\mid \Re\langle \phi,\xi\rangle=0\}\,.
$$
Fortunately, the $v_\phi^{-1}$ expression is correct.

Moreover, the correct expressions of $U_\phi$ and $u_\phi$ are
$$
U_\psi=\Pi(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \psi^\perp)
$$
and
$$
u_\phi\colon [\chi]\in U_\phi\mapsto \frac{\chi}{\langle \phi,\chi\rangle}-\phi\in \phi^\perp\,.
$$

Finally, the locally representation of $\Pi$ at $\psi$ in charts $(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\psi\},v_{-\psi})$ and $(U_\psi,u_\psi)$ is
$$
u_\psi\circ \Pi\circ v_{-\psi}^{-1}\colon v_\psi(\Pi^{-1}(U_\psi)\cap (\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\psi\}))\mapsto u_\psi(U_\psi\cap\Pi(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus\{-\psi\}))
$$

Let us observe that
\begin{align*}
v_\psi(\Pi^{-1}(U_\psi)\cap(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\psi\}))&=v_\psi((\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \psi^\perp)\cap(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\psi\}))\\
&=v_\psi(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus (\{-\psi\}\cup\psi^\perp))\\
&=\{\xi\in \mathcal H \mid \Re\langle \psi,\xi\rangle=0, |\xi|\ne 1\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
u_\psi(U_\psi\cap \Pi(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\psi\})&=u_\psi(\Pi(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \psi^\perp)\cap \Pi(\mathcal S\mathcal H\setminus \{-\psi\}))\\
&=u_\psi(U_\psi)\\
&=\psi^\perp\,.
\end{align*}

Finally,
\begin{align*}
    (u_\psi\circ \Pi\circ (\varphi_\psi^-)^{-1})(\xi)&=(u_\psi\circ \Pi)\bigg(-\frac{|\xi|^2-1}{1+|\xi|^2}\psi+\frac{2\xi}{1+|\xi|^2}\bigg)\\
    &=u_\psi((1-|\xi|^2)\psi+2\xi)\\
    &=\frac{(1-|\xi|^2)\psi+2\xi}{\langle \psi,(1-|\xi|^2)\psi+2\xi\rangle}-\psi\\
    &=\frac{(1-|\xi|^2)\psi+2\xi}{1-|\xi|^2+2\langle \psi,\xi\rangle}-\psi\\
    &=\frac{2(\xi-\langle \psi,\xi\rangle\psi)}{1-|\xi|^2+2\langle \psi,\xi\rangle}
\end{align*}